# Pass firebase reference as prop in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a firebase reference in my top level component. How can I pass this down as a prop to a child component in vue?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <NavBar />
    <router-view db="pass the db ref here" storage="pass the storage ref here" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db, storage } from './config/firebase';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    NavBar,
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the `db` and `storage` references as data properties of the root Vue instance:

```
data() {
  return { db, storage };
}
```

Then, bind them to the `<router-view>` component:

```
<router-view :db="db" :storage="storage" />
```

The child component will need to have those `props` declared:

```
props: {
  db: Object,
  storage: Object
}
```